# Making dataset from a JSON file

Tags: python, json, pandas

I am new to Machine learning. I need a small help. I have to implement SVM on a Twitter data. The data is in a JSON file and contains values like publish_time, tweet_details, etc. I have extracted the data and made functions in Python which contains each of these values. May I know what could be the next step so that I could apply SVM. I have implemented SVM on a CSV file but I am not understanding how to get the dataset in the case of JSON. I would appreciate any kind of help.

Comment: Why don't you just read the json input data and re-write it into csv?

Comment: You can use the general [json](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) module to read the data into a dictionary, or use this [function](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_json.html) to read it into a pandas DataFrame.

Comment: As @patrick mentioned, if you have json data in python, it is most likely represented in a dict data structure, so you can convert this to a pandas DataFrame using something like df = pd.DataFrame(json_data) and then work with the tabular form of the data from here

Comment: Francky_V : I cannot do it that way because I have to customize the data first.
@patrick and  Robert Milletich : Yes, I am thinking of doing so but not understanding how to start.